# CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey Error:0x80090016 with custom Key Storage Provider

Tags: c, cng, microsoft-key-storage-provider

I'm develoving a custom CNG Key Storage Provider. It works fine with some applications like Chrome, but a third party application uses the `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` method with the certificate context causing a 0x80090016 without invoking any method of my KSP.

¿Is possible to use the `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` method with a certificate with a private key stored in a Key Storage Provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the [NCryptTranslateHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncrypttranslatehandle) function documentation:

> This is a helper function intended to help
> applications and system components that currently use the CryptoAPI to
> make a graceful transition to using CNG.
>
> This function will only be successful if a CNG key storage provider is
> registered with a name or alias that is identical to the name of the
> cryptographic service provider (CSP) referred to by the hLegacyProv
> parameter.
>
> This function will perform the following steps to translate the CSP
> handle into a CNG key handle:
>
> Obtain the name of the CSP from the hLegacyProv handle. Open the CNG
> provider whose name or alias is identical to the CSP name. Obtain the
> name of the current key container in the CSP. Obtain the CryptoAPI
> key, translate it into a CNG key, and return it in the phKey
> parameter.

Registering the KSP with the same name or alias as the CSP does the trick.